# ¿Cómo manipular las propiedades de varios controles a la vez en Windows Forms por medio de su Name/identificador?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me encuentro buscando el equivalente de esta funcionalidad en `jQuery/javascript` pero para `C# Windows Forms`, por el momento no he encontrado alguna fuente que me guíe para realizar esta `función`.

Esta es la demostración de lo que busco:

Si observan, los `input text` tienen `identificadores` similares **txt**, lo único que los diferencia es el numero. Por lo tanto, para no modificar de uno por uno, realizo la llamada dinámicamente solo cambiando el último numero de cada `identificador`, en este caso modificó la propiedad `val()` de cada uno de ellos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //guardo la base de los identificadores
    var id_inputs = "#txt";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {   
        //A la base de los identificadores se agrega el numero que los termina identficando para poder setearles x valor
        $(id_inputs+i).val("valor"+ i);
    }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="text" id="txt3">
<input type="text" id="txt4">
<input type="text" id="txt5">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pero me encuentro que en `Windows Forms` varios colegas manipulan cada uno de los objetos mandándolos llamar directamente cuando los `identificadores` comparten esta similitud y solo cambia un numero. Ejemplo:

`txt1.Text = "valor1";`

`txt2.Text = "valor2";` etc...

Lo que causa que la cantidad de líneas de código crezcan innecesariamente.

Comment: Windows Forms, o *WebForms?*

Comment: @Arriel Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
   if (control is TextBox)
   {
      TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
      
      txt.Text = ...// o cualquier otra propiedad 
   }
}
```

Que se hace aquí, se recorren todos los controles que están contenidos en el formulario, y se pregunta si ese control es un **TextBox**, de serlo, pues se modifican las propiedades que deseas, poniendo los valores que deseas. Espero te sirva o al menos te de ideas.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, esa idea es algo parecida a lo que busco, mas sin embargo lo que necesito es poder manipularlos por medio de su name/id, ya que no solo busco controlar las propiedades de solo un control en específico, si no también de algunos otros diferentes que compartan las mismas propiedades. El ejemplo que puse fue a grandes rasgos de lo que busco.